# Need to get all available links using WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to get all available links in a web page using WebDriver?

Comment: Well what's 'available'? Visible you mean?

Answer (score 5):

You can get all links using below logic.

```
List<WebElement> link=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

for(WebElement ele:link)
{
     System.out.println(ele.getText());
}
```

Comment: I think you should call the "getAttribute" function on WebElement in the last line passing "href" as its argument

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
    System.out.println("No of links present="+ list.size());

    // use of for loop for iteration
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    //use of for each for iteration
    for(WebElement wb: list)
        System.out.println(wb.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Max.Mirkia, to grab urls from 'href'

modified Santoshsarma code

```
 List<WebElement> tagName = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for(WebElement ele:tagName)
    {
        String urls = ele.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println(urls);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a"));

for(WebElement link:list)                             
{
  System.out.println(link.getText());

}
```